# real valued functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $F(x,y)=H(xy)$ be a real valued function defined over non-negative reals. $H(\cdot)$ is differentiable in its argument. Take partial derivatives $F_x=yH_x(xy)$ and $F_y=xH_y(xy)$. Can we say that $H_x=H_y$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You have written down the partial derivatives incorrectly.  If $H'$ is the derivative of $H$ with respect to its arguments, then $F_x=yH'(xy)$ and $F_y=xH'(xy)$.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Multiplication is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), that is $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is defined by 
$$F:(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{+2}\longmapsto F(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$$

and has two partial derivatives: one with respect to its first variable $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and one with respect to its second one $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}$.

$H$ is such that:
$$H:u\in\mathbb{R}\longmapsto H(u)\in\mathbb{R}$$
and has only one derivative $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}H}{\mathrm{d}u}$.

Now you can derive $H(u)$ with respect to $x$, where $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ (in your example, $u(x,y)=xy$). So:

$$\dfrac{\partial H(u)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}H}{\mathrm{d}u}\,\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = H'\cdot y$$
And $\dfrac{\partial H(u)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}$.

You can try the same thing with respect to $y$.